# white in view controller before UIWebView apears

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have two view controllers with two UIWebViews. The first one has a grey background and the second one a black background. When I try to access the second one a white background appears for miliseconds.
I've setted the UIWebView background color to black in the Attribute Inspector.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about how you access 'the second one'?

Comment: I use url overriding but it also happens when I use a navigation controller with a root view controller for the relationship segue.

Comment: Fixed by clearing opaque in the Attribute Inspector